# VueJS: Enable transition only after FIRST load

Tags: vue.js

I've got this line in my vue component:

```
<p><b>You have <transition name="fade" mode="out-in"><span :key="todos_counter">{{todos_counter}}</span></transition> items</b></p>
```

The problem seems to be, because `todos_counter` is coming from `vuex` store using `MapGetters`, its real initial value is `0`, but then on the initial load it update to (say) `16`, so Vue applied the transition on the initial page-load. I only want a transition if `todos_counter` changed AFTER the first load.

So basically I want the initial load to not include ANY transition, but if after the initial component load is completed `todos_counter` changes, I do want the transition to occur.

This is really tricky, even using `watch` on the component level is hard because from the watcher's perspective `todos_count` DOES change on the first page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the approach I went with:

**HTML:**

```
<p><b>You have <transition v-bind:name="animateOn" mode="out-in"><span :key="todos_counter">{{todos_counter}}</span></transition> items</b></p>
```

**JS:**

```
    data: () => ({
        animateOn: "none",
        updatedBefore: false,
    }),

    watch: {
        todos_counter() {
            if (!this.updatedBefore) {
                this.updatedBefore = true
            }
            else {
                this.animateOn = "fade"
            }
        }
```

Bind the transition name to `animateOn` (initial value: `"none"`), and then when the `todo_counter` changes, change this value to `"fade"`. This way the element isn't animated on the first load.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, hopefully it should work God willing.

In your template:

```
<p>
    <b>
       You have 
       <!-- Added duration prop here -->
       <transition 
         name="fade" 
         mode="out-in"
         :duration="transitionDuration" 
       >
           <span 
             :key="todos_counter"
           >
               {{todos_counter}}
           </span>
       </transition> 
       items
   </b>
</p>
```

In your script:

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                // this is as if there is no transition, it's way too fast.
                transitionDuration: "1ms"
            };
        },
        mounted() {
            setTimeout(() => {
                // this will set the duration back to normal after the initial render.
                this.transitionDuration = "1000ms"
            }, 100)
        }
    }
<script>
```

Comment: I ended up doing something different, but this should work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You really need a way of determining when the data is loading so you can control the transition. Right now the value is initially rendered as 0 and then after loading it changes to 16, so the transition will play.

You can try something like this:

```vue
<p v-if="!loading">
  <b>You have <transition name="fade" mode="out-in"><span :key="todos_counter">{{todos_counter}}</span></transition> items</b>
</p>
```

```es6
computed: {
  ...mapState(['loading']),
  ...mapGetters(['todos_counter']),
}
```

`loading` must be initially true, then after the initial load it is set to false.

It doesn't have to be exactly like this, but you get the idea.

Comment: This hides the `p` initially, something I'm not interested in.